# Is there a relation between Elliptic Curves and Frobenius Numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, integer-lattices, elliptic-functions, big-picture

A CS professor yesterday asked me this query. I think there is no direct relation if any.

The frobenius number is the largest number that cannot be represented by $au+bv$ where $gcd(a,b)=1$ holds and $a,b,u,v\in\Bbb N$ holds.

Elliptic curves are isomorphic over $\Bbb C$ to $2$ dimensional lattices which at least superficially looks like $au+bv$ forms.

So is there any reason to expect no connection between elliptic functions and linear forms in $2$ variables?

Comment: @DietrichBurde frobenius map?

Comment: @DietrichBurde It was about linear forms.

Comment: and to make it clear : a complex elliptic curve $E(\mathbb{C}) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2, y^2 = 4x^3-g_{2,\Lambda}x-g_{3,\Lambda}\}$ is isomorphic by $z \mapsto (\wp(z),\wp'(z))$ to the complex torus $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Lambda$ thanks to the Weierstrass function $\wp_\Lambda(z)$ that fulfills $\wp_\Lambda'(z)^2 = 4\wp_\Lambda(z)^3-g_{2,\Lambda} \wp_\Lambda(z)-g_{3,\Lambda}$. The isomorphism is as Riemann surface [and as algebraic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#Addition_theorems).

Comment: @user1952009 so there is no connection?

Comment: I don't know "Frobenius numbers". The problem is that elliptic curves $E(k) = \{(x,y) \in k^2, y^2 = x^3+ax+b\}$ (with their algebraic group) exist over (almost) any field $k$ (but are completely different from one field to the other), so they have connection with almost everything in number theory.

Comment: And [did you see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#n_.3D_2)  it says the Frobenius number is $ab-a-b$

Comment: @user1952009 yes I know that.

Comment: @user1952009 that is not the scope of the query.

Comment: of course it is. come on. When asking a question on Frobenius numbers with $n=2$, you are asking a question on the function $g(a,b) = ab-a-b$, so you have to mention it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a connection between elliptic curves over finite fields and the *Frobenius Map*, which is the function
$$
\tau_p \colon E(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)\rightarrow E(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p),\quad \tau_p(x, y) = (x^p, y^p). 
$$
One can check that $\tau_p$ is a group homomorphism. It gives the quantity
$$
a_p=p+1-|E(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)|,
$$
called the *trace of the Frobenius*, which satisfies $|a_p|\le 2\sqrt{p}$ by Hasse.

I think that "Frobenius number" is not directly connected to elliptic curves, so you are right.

Comment: Clearly this was not the problem and we did discuss this in comments.

Comment: did you even read the first line of my query?

Comment: you did mention not directly connected but that was a side comment (more or less). I am looking for why there cannot be such connections?

Comment: @Turbo : don't be insulting with the people trying to help you. You are allowed to say "sorry but I was really meaning Frobenius numbers" instead of downvoting. Now given the fact you don't really know what are elliptic curves and Frobenius map and Frobenius numbers, it seems natural to think you meant a connection between Frobenius and elliptic curves.

Comment: @user1952009 why do you think I am insulting?

Comment: @DietrichBurde ok please delete your post so I can remove my silly query.

Comment: @DietrichBurde wait. Why do you write $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ (the algebraic closure) ? I never considered elliptic curves $E(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$, are they easier ?

Comment: @Turbo and if you want to understand elliptic curves (and elliptic functions), my comments are useful

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think the query cannot be improved. It was a naive query.